# How do I include project code in my PhantomJS QUnit test runner?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, qunit

I am using `node-qunit-phantomjs` the `PhantomJS` `QUnit` test runner. I have run into a roadblock because I have no way to include or inject the JS library the code under test needs.

The test file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>color tests</title>

    <!-- QUNIT CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/qunit.css" type="text/css"/>

    <!-- QUNIT JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/qunit.js"></script>

    <!-- IGV JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/igv-color.js"></script>

    <!-- unit test JS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="testColor.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="qunit"></div>
<div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        runColorTests();
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The code being tested is `testColor.js`.

```
function runColorTests() {

    test( "GreyScale Test", 1, function() {

        ok(igv.greyScale(45), "grey");
        console.log(igv.greyScale(45));
    });

    test( "RGB Color Test", 1, function() {

        ok(igv.rgbColor(12, 123, 23), "rgb");
        console.log(igv.rgbColor(12, 123, 23));
    });

}
```

The color library is `igv-color.js`.

```
var igv = (function (igv) {

    igv.rgbColor = function (r, g, b) {
        r = clamp(r, 0, 255);
        g = clamp(g, 0, 255);
        b = clamp(b, 0, 255);
        return "rgb(" + r + "," + g + "," + b + ")";
    };

    igv.greyScale = function (grey) {
        grey = clamp(grey, 0, 255);
        return "rgb(" + grey + "," + grey + "," + grey + ")";
    };

    function clamp(value, min, max) {
        return Math.min(Math.max(value, min), max);
    };

    return igv;

})(igv || {});
```

Notice the color library is scoped within the global variable `igv`

When I run the test: `node-qunit-phantomjs ./runTestColor.html` There is an error because the library functions are not pulled into my code. I am aware of the functions `page.injectJs` and `page.includeJs` but I see no way to use them with the test runner.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the error message you're getting? What library functions do you  mean?

Comment: I refer to ../js/igv-color.js. This is the "library" file. All functions hang off of the global "igv" variable and are not seen when I run under phantom. I want to inject (or include?) ../js/igv-color.js into phantomjs.